# Does Screen.orientation not work in simulator?

Tags: unity, mobile, screen, orientation

I use the `Screen.orientation` property to reposition my UI when the screen is rotated. But when I rotate the simulator to left or right,
`Screen.orientation` does not seem to detect the screen change.

Why is that?

```
if (    Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft
     && Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight )
{
     Button.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(112, -425.690063f, 0);
}
else
{
     Button.ShowandHide.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(112, -253.609131f, 0);
}
```

If I use `Screen.height > Screen.width`, will that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem with `Screen.orientation` - you just have a bug in your code.

This `if` condition:

```
if (    Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft
     && Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight )
```

Says "If `Screen.orientation` is *simultaneously both* `LandscapeLeft` AND `LandscapeRight`..."

But obviously the phone can't be *both* laying to the left AND laying to the right at the same time. Macroscopic objects like phones don't get to occupy two contradictory states in superposition.

So this condition is impossible, and always evaluates to `false`, meaning your `else` block is always the one that executes.

It looks like what you want here is:

```
if (    Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft
     || Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight )
```

That double-pipe `||` is "OR" not "AND". So we'll execute the first block if the phone is *either* lying to the left, OR lying to the right.

The `else` block will then trigger only if *neither* of those is true (ie. the phone is standing vertically - upright or upside-down).

Be sure to proofread your code for typos like this. 90% of the time, when you encounter a problem that looks like "is this engine used by thousands of developers and successful games completely and utterly broken, or did I just make a mistake somewhere?" the answer is usually that you made a mistake somewhere.